# Saving data via AJAX

Tags: jquery, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm using the SonataAdminBundle with a custom eeditAction.

This action displays the normal entity I'm editing, plus a calendar (full calendar)

This is to be used as an appointment booking system.

The problem I'm having is adding the appointments. When I add the first appointment all goes well. It saves the entity, closes the form and adds the event to the calendar without refreshing the page.

If I then try to re-add an appointment and save it like i did previously, it adds 2 apointments.

If I then try to add another, it adds 3, and 4 and so on.

I'm really confused as to why this is doing this.

My code is as follows:

Javascript:

```
        function ShowEventPopup(date)
        {
            $('#popupEventForm').show();
        }

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $myCalendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            firstDay: 1,
            contentHeight: 450,
            editable: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay'
            },
            events: '{{ path('fetch_events', { _sonata_admin: 'bm.crm.admin.event'} ) }}',
            dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                $('#event_name').val("");

                ShowEventPopup(date);

                $('#EventForm').submit(function(event)
                {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var url = Routing.generate('create_event', { 'id': {{ object.id }} , _sonata_admin: 'bm.crm.admin.event' });
                    var form = $(this);

                    // ajax call
                    $.post(url, form.serialize(), function(data) {

                                if(data.code == "OK") {
                                    var due_date_month = form.find('#event_due_date_month').val();
                                    var due_date_day = form.find('#event_due_date_day').val();
                                    var due_date_year = form.find('#event_due_date_year').val();
                                    var event_name = form.find('#event_name').val();
                                    var due_date = due_date_year+"-"+due_date_month+"-"+due_date_day;

                                    // refresh the calendar
                                    var myNewEvent = {
                                        "title": event_name,
                                        "start": due_date,
                                        "end": due_date
                                    };

                                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar("renderEvent", myNewEvent, true);

                                } else {
                                    alert("NOT SAVED");
                                }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
```

`edit.html.twig`

```
        <form id="EventForm" class="well" method="post" {{ form_enctype(formEvent) }}>
        {{ form_errors(formEvent) }}
        <div>
             {{ form_errors(formEvent.name) }}
             {{ form_label(formEvent.name) }}
             {{ form_widget(formEvent.name) }}
        </div>

         <div class="due_date">
             {{ form_errors(formEvent.due_date) }}
             {{ form_label(formEvent.due_date) }}
             {{ form_widget(formEvent.due_date) }}
         </div>

         <div>
              {{ form_errors(formEvent.due_time) }}
              {{ form_label(formEvent.due_time) }}
              {{ form_widget(formEvent.due_time) }}
         </div>

         <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" id="btnPopupClose" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <input type="submit" id="btnPopupSave" value="Add Appointment" />
         </div>

         {{ form_row(formEvent.__token)}}
         </form>
```

`editAction()`

```
    $form = $this->createForm(new EventType() );

    if($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $form->submit($request);

        if($form->isValid()) {

            $msg = "Success!";
            $code = "OK";

            // save values
            $em->persist($event);
            $em->flush();

        } else {
            $validator = $this->container->get('validator');
            $errors = $validator->validate($event);
            $msg = "<ul>";
            foreach ($errors as $err) {
                $msg.= "<li>".$err->getMessage() . "</li>";
            }
            $msg .= "</ul>";
            $code = "ERR";

        }

        // return values back to the view
        $response = new Response(json_encode(array('code' => $code, 'msg' => $msg)));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;

    }
```

The form is loaded via `twitter bootstrap modal`. It seems that the issue is when I close the modal and then reopen it, it seems to then re-submit the form `n` times.

Is there a way to `destroy` the modal so the form doesn't constantly re-submit data?

Thanks

Comment: is the question all about "destroy" the bootstrap modal ?
I only aks because you provide so much information and your added tags give me the impression it is a symfony - sonata bundle problem.

Comment: Well I thought it was, but now I'm not so sure. The main problem seems to be the modal. I'm also using fullcalendar, as these are appointments added. Click on a date, modal appears, add 1 appointment, add a 2nd, close window. Click on new date, add appointment, adds 3 to my db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i want to clear/destroy a modal using bootstrap (this is for version > 3, the name of the event differs)

```
  $('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal'); //destroy the binded data every time the box closes
  });
```

in addition

```
function closeModalBox() {

  $('#modal').modal('hide');
  $('.modal-content').html(''); //reset the content html when closing the modal
}
```

hope it helps and you dont have other sonata admin bundle issues ;)

Comment: Unfortunatley, that doesn't work. I'll post my full code for you

Comment: just read over your javascript again ... just to dismiss that : you bind the form submit event inside of the click event of the calendar might be that you attach the event listener multiple time by doing so

Comment: Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: if that is your error it needs to be avoided ;) ... ok where is that javascript you posted above located ? is it inside of a template ? because you are using the twig `path` function. You could try to bind the submit button to your submit function that would at least avoid that the form bind event will be attached every time you click inside your calendar.

Comment: i modified the jsfiddle and at least the request / events are not send/fired `N` times (same for the close event)

http://jsfiddle.net/2ufxJ/16/